# Fine tuning a dotplot in R's lattice package

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to plot a bunch of ROC areas for different datasets and different algorithms. 
I have three variables: "Scheme" which specifies the algorithm used, "Dataset" is the dataseet that the algorithm is being tested on, and "Area_under_ROC".

I am using the lattice library in R, with the following command:

> dotplot(Scheme ~ Area_under_ROC | Dataset, data = simulationSummary, layout = c(4,6))

and this is what I get:

[dotplot of Scheme vs. Area_under_ROC conditioned on Dataset](http://s18.postimage.org/ebuj2ddjt/dotplot.jpg)

What I'd like to know is

- How can make the labels on the y-axis readable? Right now, they're all squeezed together.
- How can I re-arrange the panel in such a way that the datasets marked with "100" form the last column, but the other columns stay the same?

I'd very much appreciate any comments or pointers. 
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. Use a smaller font size for y-axis labels, e.g. `scale=list(y=list(cex=.6))`. An alternative would be to preserve uniform font size, but separate your output on several pages (this can be controlled with `layout=`), or, probably better, to show all data from the same dataset (A to F, hence 4 points for each algorithm) or by sample size (10 to 100, hence 6 points for each algorithm) with a `group=` option. I would personally create two factors, `sample.size` and `dataset.type` for that.
2. Relevel your factor `Dataset`, so that the dataset you are interested appear where `layout` will put them, or (better!) use `index.cond` to specify a particular arrangement for your 24 panels. E.g.,

   ```
   dfrm <- data.frame(algo=gl(11, 1, 11*24, labels=paste("algo", 1:11, sep="")), 
                      type=gl(24, 11, 11*24, labels=paste("type", 1:24, sep="")),
                      roc=runif(11*24))
   p <- dotplot(algo ~ roc | type, dfrm, layout=c(4,6), scale=list(y=list(cex=.4)))
   ```

   will arrange panels in sequential order, from bottom left to top right (`type1` in bottom left panel, `type24` in top right panel), while

   ```
   update(p, index.cond=list(24:1))
   ```

   will arrange panels in the reverse order. Just specify a `list` with expected panel locations.

---

Here is an example of what I have in mind with Point 1 and the use of two factors instead of one. Let us generate another artificial dataset:

```
dfrm <- data.frame(algo=gl(11, 1, 11*24, labels=paste("algo", 1:11, sep="")),
                   dataset=gl(6, 11, 11*24, labels=LETTERS[1:6]),
                   ssize=gl(4, 11*6, 11*24, labels=c(10,25,50,100)), 
                   roc=runif(11*24))
xtabs(~ dataset + ssize, dfrm)  # to check allocation of factor levels 
dotplot(algo ~ roc | dataset, data=dfrm, group=ssize, type="l", 
        auto.key=list(space="top", column=4, cex=.8, title="Sample size", 
                      cex.title=1, lines=TRUE, points=FALSE))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much chl! I really appreciate your help. I haven't tried your comments after your edit yet, but your original suggestions worked like a charm. The labels on the y-axis were very small though. I have to figure out a way to make them more readable. One thing I didn't clarify in my original post was that the numbers after letters in dataset names don't indicate size, but rather the amount of signal in the data.  A100 is all signal and no noise, but A10, is 90 percent noise and 10 percent signal. The datasets are all the same size. Many Many thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Additionally to  [chl answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9701302/168747) after splitting `Dataset` type to Type and Size you could use [`useOuterStrips`](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/#useOuterStrips&theme=default) function from latticeExtra package.

To get more space for labels you could "transpose" plot.

```
# prepare data:
simulationSummary$Dataset_type <- substr(simulationSummary$Dataset, 1, 5)
simulationSummary$Dataset_size <- substr(simulationSummary$Dataset, 6, 10)

# to gets proper order force factor levels:
simulationSummary$Dataset_size <- factor(simulationSummary$Dataset_size,
    levels = c("10", "25", "50", "100"))

library(latticeExtra)
useOuterStrips(dotplot(
     Scheme ~ Area_under_ROC | Dataset_type*Dataset_size,
     data = simulationSummary,
     layout = c(4,6)
))
```

[image: Dotplot]

Or use vertical dotplot:

```
useOuterStrips(dotplot(
     Area_under_ROC ~ Scheme | Dataset_size*Dataset_type,
     data = simulationSummary, horizontal=FALSE,
     layout = c(4,6), scales=list(x=list(rot=90))
))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Marek! I really appreciate your comments. The label size was in fact a problem and this will hopefully help me to fix it.

Comment: (+1) I always forget about outer strips!